# Transactional Email List in Magento Empty when add new template

Tags: php, magento, email, transactional

I'm trying to add a new email template via adminhtml -> system -> transactional email -> new template, then default template not loading

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a default template from the dropdown first and then overwrite with your own.

Comment: hi, default template not loading, System->Transactional Emais-> Add New Template then get Template dropdown blank

Comment: I have a strange issue, we have a few custom created extensions which we have created. If I go make the active status to false, then the transaction template feature works.

Comment: You need to turn off extensions one by one until you can determine which is at fault and then go from there